# C++ which constructor will be called

Tags: c++

If suppose in a class I have two constructors

```
Room()
{
length = 0;
width = 0;
}
```

&

```
Room(int value = 8)
{
length = width = 8;
}
```

Now if from main I call using:

```
Room obj1;
obj.display();
```

which constructor will be called or will it throw error? I think that it will throw error as compiler will not be able to call the correct constructor because of two same type of constructors present.Is it correct ?

Comment: Maybe you should try it.

Comment: You're gonna be downvoted if you didn't even try it, you must do research effort before posting...

Comment: I cant try it as of now because I dont have C++ compiler on my system.Otherwise I would have done it instead of asking here

Comment: It's ambiguous, and won't compile.

Comment: @SampritiPanda I know about ideone.com but I can't open it here because of unnecessary office censorship

Comment: what is `display` and what is the purpose of `value` ? This is bad code anyway, even if you will manage to make this work you shouldn't take this path at all.

Comment: @user2485710 I am not making it to work, I am trying to work on error identification by looking at code.`display()` definition here is not important and that is why I have not written above.The core is the constructors

Comment: look at the line number first, errors code are not everything, in this case it's easy to debug that, but usually you should locate the problem first, than try to deduce what the real issue consist of.

Comment: http://ideone.com/y5KTpP

Comment: Where are you declaring member variable `display()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call of overloaded ‘Room()’ is ambiguous`

so it won't be compile

[image]

and you can use [codepad](http://codepad.org/) as an online compiler

Answer (score 0):

> A default constructor is a constructor that either has no parameters, or if it has parameters, all the parameters have default values.

In this case code will not compile... You can read more about default constructor from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this will be the complete program

```
#include <iostream>
struct Room
{
    int length;
    int width;
    Room()
    {
        length = 0;
        width = 0;
    }
    Room(int value = 8)
    {
        (void)value;
        length = 8;
        width = 8;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Room obj1; // ambiguous call
    std::cout << obj1.length << "\n";
    return (0);
}
```

This code will not compile because of an ambiguous call to the constructor of `Room` for the declaration of `obj1`.